# Macro properly runs in VBE not from add-in button in Excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for help on the following piece of code. While it works fine in the VB editor, it throws an error when I run the macro from the add-in button I added in the Excel file itself. Instead of saving the new workbook, it tries saving the original macro-enabled workbook. I can't use the SaveAs method because of permission issues, which I'm circumventing by prompting the user to choose the file path. Any help would be much appreciated! Please also feel free to correct my code below.

```
Sub Forecast()

Dim saveResult As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Define variable name of new workbook
NewWBname = "Revenue Forecast " & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")

'Copy data from macro-enabled file to new workbook
Sheets(Array("Revenue Forecast", "Probability Table")).Copy

'Rename $A$1
With ActiveWorkbook
    .Worksheets("Revenue Forecast").Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "Revenue Forecast " & Year(Now()) + 1
        'Autofit all columns for both sheets on new workbook
        For Each Wsht In Worksheets
            With Wsht.UsedRange
                .EntireColumn.AutoFit
            End With
        Next Wsht
    'Open Save As Dialogue Box to prompt user to choose file path
    saveResult = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show(NewWBname, Arg4:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook)

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is your code in the workbook you're trying to process or is it in the PERSONAL.XLSB file so it can be used across workbooks? It's a bit tricky using `ThisWorkbook` since running it in the VBA editor will reference whatever workbook the module is in. If that's the correct workbook, then it's fine. Otherwise, `ActiveWorkbook` will give you the excel file you have open and active.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I think it sits as a module of my .xlsm file. Do you recommend changing to add under personal.xlsb? Added a screenshot if it helps visualize the problem. As a note, I'm not trying to save the new workbook as a macro-enabled one, just a regular .xslx file.

Comment: Have a look at the [`Workbook.SaveAs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas) Method

Comment: Thanks, I initially was going to use that method but need to circumvent issues saving directly on my organization's Dropbox, which is why I want to prompt the user to choose the path (and this method has worked so far in the VBE). What would you change in the code above to make sure that Excel identifies that the newly created file (with extension .xlsx) is the one to save, not the macro-enabled template?